# New to Ubuntu - 12.04.1 Kernel Panic on Installation

Tags: 12.04, kernel, dell

I'm a complete Ubuntu and even Linux newbie. I'm learning here, so I'm grateful for any info to help me learn more about this.

I have a Dell Dimension 2400 with a Pentium 4 and 1GB of RAM. It's older but it's only going to be doing some small stuff for me when I get it up and going. I've tried installing several versions of Linux (but I really, really want Ubuntu) and I keep getting a similar kernel panic message. The problem is I don't have a clue what that means or how to begin fixing it. I would appreciate any help to get my machine up and going.

I have already tried

1. Installing alternate Ubuntu versions
2. Burning multiple 12.04.1 disks
3. Installing other versions of Linux

I have a picture of the screen to share; however, I can't post due to the fact that I don't have enough reputation points on this forum because I'm a newbie. I would be happy to email you a pic, if you think you can help.

Comment: welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please upload screen-shots to any image hosting sites and post the link here as a comment and we can embed it to your question.

Comment: Your system is quite old and may not support a feature called PAE which the default Ubuntu installer now requires. Please try installing the 32-bit (i386) version of Xubuntu or Lubuntu instead.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1194021/ Here is what boot repair gave me.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).